# How to disable to email notification during the migration and keep existing the workitem ID in the target project from the source

Tags: azure-devops-migration-tools

I have some question regarding the VSTS Sync Migration Tool (Migration Tool for Azure DevOps) where  I am using the version v11.9.31 not the latest one v11.9.47 in which I am able to migrate all the workitems along with attached, related count files and along with the history itself.

We  have the below two concern. Please see below.

1. People are getting emailed / notified of workitems during migration
2. During the work items migration can we migrate the existing workitem ID itself rather than creating the new ID in the target project.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an answer for your first question, but regarding the your second question, it is not possible to have the have the workitem ID remain the same. This is because when a workitem is created, the ID is create automatically by the ADO service. If you need to retain the source ID you may want to write it to a new field on target called sourceID (you can name it anything you want).

Answer (score 0):

1. Disable email notification:

Azure devops > Organisation > Organisation Settings > Global Notifications > Settings > select Do not deliver
To verify check the Statistics tab to see how many events were generated

Also, Go to
Azure Devops > Organisaiton > select your project > Project settings > notifications > Delivery settings > select Do not deliver and save

The only way to block emails to mention is to remove that user from Organisation > Organisation Settings > User
This way it won't allow mentions and the admin user will receive email
"XXX cannot be mentioned in Bug xxx" so before migration filter these emails to a folder to avoid bombarding of emails from devops.

2. Retain same id:
   I don't think that's possible. The whole idea is to create new work items on the target Organisation

Comment: This is good but will only stop global notifications. If someone has a personal notification it ill still trigger.